# Maximum number of shapefiles for merge tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcpy

I have over 180,000 shapefiles that I have to merge (or append) into a final shapefile. 
I have written a python script to do so which uses the acrpy.append_management tool. However the runtime is too long.

I was thinking of maybe testing out the merge tool but I am skeptical that it will accept this many shapefiles and merge them together in a reasonable amount of time.

Does anyone have any experience in merging large datasets? 
Is there an efficient way to merge large amounts of shapefiles?

Comment: Without going into details, there is a 2 GB limit in the filesize of individual parts of shapefile. With 180000 shapefiles you probably exceed that. Use some database instead.

Comment: I've never merged so many feature classes, BUT 1) check your field mapping before merging and 2) do NOT use shapefiles anymore

Answer (score 3):

Consider using Dissolve. This will write the output to a new feature class but it may be more efficient. In my experience dissolve operations have taken less time than merge. Run a benchmark to determine which is faster.

There may be some issue with merge/dissolve wrt to performance and dissolving circular arcs (such as results of buffering points, polylines). Densifying input geometry prior to running merge/dissolve may increase performance.

You may also want to consider using software other that ESRI. Some users experience increase persomrmace using Postgres for example (see linked threads)

[Measuring performance difference between Merge and Append in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28244/is-there-a-difference-in-performance-between-merge-and-append-in-arcgis)

[Improving upon ArcGIS Buffer/Dissolve performance?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/630/how-to-improve-upon-arcgis-buffer-dissolve-performance)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the great ideas.

Unfortunately I was stuck using arcGIS as getting admin privileges at my workplace is near impossible.

Basically what I ended up doing was appending 100 files at a time rather than 1 at a time. This reduced the runtime to just over 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

First of all 180,000 shapefiles is big number as already suggested please do care about the 2GB limit and the field mapping.

Second, some time back I got some shapfiles and I was also not happy with the performance of arcpy merge/append. So I have tried pyshp and I was very happy with the performance.

Complete merge function you will find here.
http://geospatialpython.com/2011/02/merging-lots-of-shapefiles-quickly.html
and an updated version here
http://geospatialpython.com/2014/06/merging-shapefiles-with-pyshp-and-dbfpy.html

I am assuming you don't have any Unicode characters.

Please do share your experience.